# Showing that $ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}\;{dx}=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{2}{\sqrt{2-\sin^2{x}}}\;{dx}?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can we show that $ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}\;{dx}=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{2}{\sqrt{2-\sin^2{x}}}\;{dx}? $

It feels like it should be simple, but I've tried many things and no luck.

Comment: Note that this is not a general result, $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}\;{dx} \neq \int \frac{2}{\sqrt{2-\sin^2{x}}}\;{dx}$. I assume you want a result that doesn't involve actually evaluating this integral?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\sin (x) = u $, we get
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt u \sqrt{1 - u^2}}du = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt u \sqrt{(1 - u)(1+u)}}du$$
Again let $u = \cos ^2 y $

$$ \int_{\pi/2}^0 \frac{-2 \cos (y)\; \sin (y) \;dy}{\cos (y) \; \sin (y) \sqrt{1 + \cos^2 y}} = \int_0^{\pi \over 2} \frac{2}{\sqrt{2 - \sin^2 x}} dx $$

Answer (score 3):

To transform the RHS into the LHS: Let $u=\cos^2(x)$, then $u=\sin(t)$.